# Nothing happens when I try to apply an ActionListener to a JButton to change the content of the JLabel

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

I need a way to create an ActionListener that when a JButton is pressed, it updates the content of 7 different JLabels to display the information in the form of text.

The data is retrieved from methods called from an external JAR file. The methods return ArrayList. I attempted to convert the ArrayList into a String, and tried to change the JLabel content with setText().

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import api.anAPI.THEAPINAME;


public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    private MainGUI maingui;
    private SubPanel subpanel;
    private static THEAPINAME anAPI =new THEAPINAME("XyP0D75oRCGrLE78","x47ka5jmOGaJ2zvw");
    static ArrayList<String> nameList =new ArrayList<String>();
private String names;


     public Controller(MainGUI maingui,SubPanel subpanel){

        this.maingui = maingui;
        this.SubPanel = subpanel;

        MainGUI.getSearchBtn().addActionListener(this);


        nameList.addAll(anAPI.getNames());

        for (String s: nameList){

         names+= s+"\t";
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         SubPanel.label1.setText(names);
    //6 more Labels. 
    }

}
```

An additional, because I have 7 JLabels, would I need to do 7 getLabel methods? Or is there a way to get them all with just 1 method.

I am not entirely sure what I am doing incorrectly, it could be that the getMethods I used returned the wrong widget in question as the code for the GUI was not done by me but by a teammate and he had done a really poor job of making it clear for us.

**UPDATE:**
Fixed up the GUI to make it clearer, so I think that is no longer the problem. Now I think the problem might be that I did not convert the contents of the ArrayList into a String in the way I thought.

The desired function of the code is when the JButton is clicked on, the JLabels in question are all updated to their relevant data.

**addController method**

```
public void addController(Controller controller){
        control = controller;
        jb1.addActionListener(control);

    }
```

Comment: Did you test if `actionPerformed` executed? Put `System.out.println(names)` to the below `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {` and check what is printing.

Comment: It looks like it isn't printing out anything.

Comment: It seems api does not return anything. Make some test to find where is the error. For example put `System.out.println(nameList.size());` after the `nameList.addAll(anAPI.getNames());`. So you can check if api return anything.

Comment: The api does return things, the name anAPI is just a placeholder name.

Comment: Are you clearing the `nameList` in anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really describe what the problem is of your current code.

You can add a method say `getLabels()` in `SubPanel` class to return all of its labels, or you can add a method `setLabelText(String text)` to set text for all of its labels by extending or directly modifying `SubPanel` class.

**UPDATE**

You have several very confusing parts in your code.

In your constructor, it should be `this.subpanel = subpanel` and then it should be `maingui.getSearchBtn().addActionListener(this)`, also in method `actionPerformed` it should be `subpanel.label1.setText(names)`. These might not be your problems though since you didn't say it's the code you're actually running.

Looks like that you haven't created any instance of class `Controller` thus the code in it never gets executed.

You need to have some code outside of you `Controller` class like this:

```
   MainGUI maingui;
   SubPanel subpanel;
   // they're somehow initialized

   Controller controller = new Controller(maingui, subpanel);
```

Comment: The problem is nothing happens. My desired output is when a JButton is clicked I want to update the contents of the JLabel to whatever is obtained by the api method. Am I supposed to use a MouseListener?

Comment: @LovesPie The code should work. The only thing I guess is that did you ever create a `Controller` instance using `new Controller(gui, panel)` and pass in the UI component instances `MainGui` and `SubPanel`?

Comment: What do you mean? Like `new Controller();`?

Comment: @LovesPie Yes. If you've only defined your class `Controller` and never used it anywhere, then your UI won't change because you didn't apply your controller to these components.

Comment: I've tried doing it, but it only returns an error message stating that the constructor is undefined.

Comment: I've initiated a Controller in the MainGUI and made an addController method to add the ActionListener to the JButton I want. Still, nothing happens when I run the code. I've also fixed the syntax errors. I have even added quotations on name like so `"name"` in order to see if it at least changes the JLabel contents. Still nothing

Comment: @LovesPie Can you show that part of the code as well?